# asset-merger fails to load less font-awesome with .@{}

Tags: php, less, kohana, font-awesome

I' trying to `@import` font-awesome in my project with `less` files. It worked well before but now I changed the way to import it, instead of:

```
echo Assets::factory($filename)->css("application.less", array('processor' => 'cssmin'))->render();
```

I load an `application.less` that `@import` itself all the files. (css/less)

But I get the following error:

`Exception [ 0 ]: parse error: failed at`{`C:\wamp\www\haras-des-cybeles-du-luberon\assets\themes\backoffice\styles\/font-awesome/core.less on line 4`

**MODPATH\asset-merger\vendor\lessphp\lessc.inc.php [ 3144 ]**

```
3139            $loc = "line: $line";
3140        }
3141 
3142        // TODO this depends on $this->count
3143        if ($this->peek("(.*?)(\n|$)", $m, $count)) {
3144            throw new exception("$msg: failed at `$m[1]` $loc");
3145        } else {
3146            throw new exception("$msg: $loc");
3147        }
3148    }
```

Because it basically worked before with the same plugin I'm thinking that's a plugin issue. https://github.com/OpenBuildings/asset-merger

I think the less code is okay, even if I never saw this syntax before.
I there any workaround to make it work here? I'm wondering about change the regex. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Update the vendor `lessphp` module from 3.8 to 4.0. Fix also the bootstrap 3 mixins that couldn't compile with the 3.8 version.